# Angular Social Login - Google sign up window does not pop up in many browsers

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-social-login

I'm using Angular 15 for my web app, and I need to implement Google Sign In functionality to register/login a user with Google credentials. I already set up the app on Google Identity by following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid), then installed angularx-social-login and also followed the guide [there](https://github.com/abacritt/angularx-social-login) to create the login button.

So in app.module.ts:

```js
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              'MY_CLIENT_ID',
              {
                oneTapEnabled: false
              }
            )
          }
        ],
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
```

Then I use a custom component, LoginPage, to show the button and other stuff.
In login-page.component.html:

```html
<asl-google-signin-button type="icon" text="signin_with" ></asl-google-signin-button>
```

In login-page.component.ts:

```js
...
ngOnInit(): void {

    // Subscribe to google authorization service
    this.socialAuthService.authState.subscribe((socialUser) => {
      if (socialUser) {
        const idToken = socialUser.idToken;
        const provider = socialUser.provider;
        if (provider == "GOOGLE" && this.canPerformGoogleSignIn) {
          this.googleSignIn(idToken);
        }
      }
    });

  }
...
googleSignIn(token: string): void {

...
    // Register user via Google Sign In (by calling my back-end)
    this.authService.signUpWithGoogle(token).subscribe({
      next: (jwtAuthenticationResponse: {accessToken:string, refreshToken:string, id:number, email:string}) => {
        ...
      },
      complete: () => {
        ...
      },
      error: () => {
        ...
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This works fine on Mozilla Firefox and Safari, however in other browsers (Brave, Chrome, Edge) when I click the sign in button nothing happens, not even an error on the console.

I tried to search for a solution but I found nothing relevant. Not event the github page for Angular Social Login has issues on that.

If anyone could help me, thanks in advance.